# How do i take a screenshot with camera clearly in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]
[Original picture]

[image]
[The picture taken in unity]

I wanna take a screenshot with camera in unity. i can get a screenshot with camera but it looks weird like second picture. how can i solve this problem?

```
public void ScreenShot(int imgName) 
{ 
    RenderTexture activeRenderTexture = RenderTexture.active; RenderTexture.active =        targetCam.targetTexture;   
    targetCam.Render();

    Texture2D image = new Texture2D(targetCam.targetTexture.width, targetCam.targetTexture.height);
    _texture = image;
    image.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, targetCam.targetTexture.width, targetCam.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);
    image.Apply();
    RenderTexture.active = activeRenderTexture;

    byte[] bytes = image.EncodeToPNG();


}
```

This is the code used in unity

Comment: I never had a problem using the code from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5nENoQN4Tw) tutorial. You could try it out if you don't find a solution.

Comment: What about `ScreenShot.CaptureScreenshot()` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture.html?